# Directories in codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller, directory, http-status-code-404

I have two directories within my codeigniter controller.

/controllers/admin/

- dashboard.php
- content.php
- enquiries.php

/controllers/members/

- profile.php
- chat.php
- settings.php

Because the directory folders are not themselves controllers I can't perform any functions if the user browses to the root of the directory.

Example if the user browses to

```
 /localhost/admin/
```

a view won't be loaded and will not show a 404. This lets users know that the directory does exist, giving me a security risk because people will know that I have an admin directory.

How is it possible to show a 404 message if the user browses to the root of the directory folder???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this in config/routes.php:

`$route['admin'] = 'errors/page_missing';`

$route['members'] = 'errors/page_missing';

... where Errors is a controller with a method of page_missing, where you load a 'file not found' view.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is creating the default controller `welcome.php` in the directories I wan't to *hide* and add the show_404() function. Like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to fiddle with routes or rewrite rules. Simple and clean.